# flex ribbon bar

Tags: apache-flex, ribbon

Anybody knows a good free Office 2007-styled Ribbon bar component? I googled this for long time...but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why a TabNavigator and a ButtonBar won't work?

If so, I'd love to hear how a Ribbon is different than that.

Comment: We have is too(really!) many tabs to use simple TabNavigator or ButtonBar.

We developed our RibbonBar based on LinkButtonBar(on top) and HDivedBoxes(on bottom). But our customer tells us that it's ugly... We want to get normal(but free) ribbonbar

Comment: I still don't understand why a Ribbon is different than a TabNavigator w/ ButtonBars in it.  How will using a Ribbon solve your problem of having too many options?